# Balloon chat application issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing a simple chat application and I want to show balloons similar to the `iphone`'s [sms app](http://www.gearlive.com/blogimages/gallery/iphone-unboxing/24-iphone-sms_medium.jpg).

So I am doing an `Activity` with a `ListView` with a certain layout.
This are my layouts:

```
/* Activity Layout */ 
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

     <ListView android:id="@+id/chat_log"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:stackFromBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
         android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         android:clickable="false"
     />

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

   <EditText android:id="@+id/chat_input_text"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         />

         <Button android:id="@+id/chat_send_button"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="@string/chat_send_button"
         />

     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Other:

```
/* Row Layout */
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/userprofile_view"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/chat_ballon_left" >

 <TextView
  android:id="@+id/chat_message"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:text="haasdasdasdasdasdasdasdoo" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMr91.png).

My issues:

- The gray line which I would like to remove.
- Text is not using the whole space.
- Somehow even thought I've added `android:clickable="false"` the balloons are clickable.

Comment: Fixed the gray line with: `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: try setting the alignment for the text to the left, your picture looks like it is centered.

Comment: @schwiz: Actually it's was an issue with the 9patch. Using one for android made it look cool. So I am missing how to remove the highlight from each row in the `ListView`

Comment: Fixed my last issue setting a selector in the `ListView` with `android:listSelector` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FrameLayout` is unnecessary, so use the TextView as a root element (with the chat_ballon_left background of course). Set the width to `match_parent` so that the text takes the whole space.

BTW nice baloons, don't forget to have hdpi versions too :)